# How does my encrypted /home work, and how can I get it to work via cl on another linux distro?

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

I'm using an encrypted /home, but I have no idea how it works. I'm trying to install Arch Linux and use commandline tools like ecryptfs, but I can't figure out how to mount my ubuntu encrypted /home. Someone responded to [my question on the Arch Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1265863#p1265863) and said that I needed my passphrase and salt, but I don't know what either of those is, or where to find them.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to run

```
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase
```

from the command line to retrieve and record your generated passphrase.

(If you encrypt your home directory during installation, Ubuntu will show that message when you log in to your new system.)